# Trying to get more than 20 followers to display, how can i loop this to give me more?

Tags: java, twitter4j

My code reads

```
    long cursor = -1;
    String userID = "username";
    PagableResponseList<User> followers = twitter1.getFollowersList(userID, cursor);

    for(User follower : followers) {

        String followersList = follower.getScreenName();
        System.out.println(followersList);

    }
```

This will give me a list of twenty followers, and I understand that I can get more but I cant figure out how to.

Comment: Pageable should be a clear hint...

Comment: the followers object contains a hasNext method to check if there is another page and a method to get the next cursor. You can simply loop your code until hasNext is false.